# Why did not highlight current selected menu in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

working with Laravel 5.6 and I have sidebar.blade.php blade file to include with other blade file to show side menu bar,

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
     .nav-sidebar li.active{
      /*your css code here*/
     }
    </style>

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" >
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li style="margin-left:20px;">
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">  {{ Auth::user()->name }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acxian<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

            <li><a href="{{route('vehicles.myads')}}">My Ads</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="">Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Invitation</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
        </ul>

          <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Project Reports
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

      </ul>
    </div> 

    </div>

    <script>

       $('.nav-sidebar').on('click','li', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      });
    </script>
```

but when I click sedebar menu and visit relavent pages. current menu item is not highlighted(selected). how can fix this problem?

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery in the sidebar? If you load it before or after again, this will lead to issues, since it will be reinitiated...strange place to put this.
However: I dont see how this should work? If someone clicks on that link, it will add the class active and at the same time reload the sidebar in the next page view. Its not like the sidebar will stay the same as on the side before. It will re-render again and the click action is not initiated.
If you want to do this properly I guess you need to work with the URL or use laravel features to see which page is the current one.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, your code will add a class on click. But on click it will also load a new page in which the onclick function will no be initiated.

However you could use some serverside code to get the job done:

```
<a href="..."><li class="{{ Request::is('vehicles') ? 'active' : '' }}">Vehicles</li></a>
<a href="..."><li class="{{ Request::is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}">Home</li></a>
```

If you want to get the same result with a js solution, I guess you need to get and compare the URL-String to a certain result which is probably much more complicated then doing it with laravels blade functions.

Hope this helps!